# VBScript Error "End of Statement" in .vbs File with SendKeys Method

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, compiler-errors, sendkeys

I am trying to resolve an error code in my VBScript file that is occurring in the code below when I use the send keys method. I am calling this .vbs file from a batch file that has a parameter that I store here as the variable filename.

Here is my .vbs file:

```
 Set args = WScript.Arguments
 arg1 = args.Item(0)

 Dim filename

 filename = ""&arg1&""

 WshShell.Run("C:\root\bin\root.exe")
 WshShell.AppActivate "Administrator: Command Prompt"
 WshShell.SendKeys ".x analysis.C"
 WshShell.SendKeys ".x double_gaus.C"
 WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf")"
 WshShell.SendKeys ".q"

 WScript.Quit 1
```

The error code coming out of the command prompt window when the batch file proceesds into the .vbs file is:

```
C:\...\Root_VBS_Script_1.vbs(12, 46) Microsoft 
VBScript compilation error: Expected end of statement
```

What is the problem in my code? And are there any other problems?

Comment: Did you try to change WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf")" to WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf&")" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use & to concatenate the strings. You missed that in line 12:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf")"
```

should be

```
WshShell.SendKeys "c1->SaveAs("&filename&.pdf&")"
```